# Books Recommendation that contains about Versine

Tags: trigonometry, book-recommendation

What is recommendations for the best books of trigonometry contain material about versine, coversine and other trigonometric functions that are rarely used, basic trigonometry, and concept about deriving Trigonometry identities?

Comment: I don't know whether any book published since 1900 has anything to say about the versine and coversine.

Comment: You could look up the so-called haversine formula for distance on a sphere. That formula is still used today, though usually with the haversine translated into something involving the sine function (since computer math libraries usually don’t implement haversine directly).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is one recent example I have seen that briefly treats the *versed sine function*, $\operatorname{vers} x$, and its inverse, $\operatorname{vers}^{-1} x$, as an exercise. See pages 167 and 168 of:

*How to Integrate It: A practical guide to finding elementary integrals* by S. Stewart (Cambridge University Press, 2018)

Here the derivatives of the $\operatorname{vers} x$ and $\operatorname{vers}^{-1} x$ are found, the indefinite integral that leads to $\operatorname{vers}^{-1} x$ considered, and $\operatorname{vers}^{-1} x$ expressed in terms of the inverse cosine function presented. Not much I know, but you may find it a helpful start.

Comment: even though this is not what I mean, but you've shown a good book about integrals. Thanks ^

Comment: The actual title is, of course, How to Integrate It. https://www.cambridge.org/core/books/how-to-integrate-it/6030DFD3F3E36C296DDAD3228478FD25

Comment: Yes, my mistake.